# Python, ctypes and mmap

Tags: python, ctypes

I am wondering if it is possible for the ctypes package to interface with mmap.

Currently, my module allocates a buffer (with `create_string_buffer`) and then passes that using `byref` to my libraries `mylib.read` function. This, as the name suggests, reads data into the buffer. I then call `file.write(buf.raw)` to write the data to disk. My benchmarks, however, show this to be far from optimal (time spent in `file.write` is time better spent in `mylib.read`).

I am therefore interested in knowing if ctypes can interoperate with mmap. Given an `mmap.mmap` instance and an offset how can I get a pointer (`c_void_p`) into the address space?

Comment: Python has a [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module.

Comment: @Seth the `mmap.mmap` instance I was referring to is from that module. I wish to know how instances of it can interface with ctypes.

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing this in Python? Low-level pointer juggling is better suited to C or its ilk. It's not too hard to write C modules to interface nicely with Python, either.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I thought you were trying to roll your own mmap interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `mmap` object "supports the writable buffer interface", therefore you can use the [from_buffer](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer) class method, which all `ctypes` classes have, with the `mmap` instance as the argument, to create a `ctypes` object just like you want, i.e., sharing the memory (and therefore the underlying file) that the `mmap` instance has mapped.  I imagine, in specific, that you'll want a suitable `ctypes` [array](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-arrays).

Comment: An excellent example of this: https://github.com/serdardalgic/Code_Snippets/blob/master/Python-Examples/mmap/shared_memory_write.py

Comment: Will this truly result in just a view of the mmap, with no behavioral differences? `(ctypes.c_ubyte * mmap_obj.size()).from_buffer(mmap_obj)` looks dangerously like the whole data might be loaded into memory at once rather than lazily ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the operating system is going to be doing readahead for read() anyway.  You're going to be blocking either in read() or write()--one or the other will bottleneck the operation--but even though you're blocking in one, that doesn't mean the other isn't taking place for you behind the scenes.  That's the job of every multitasking operating system.

If you use mmap for this, you're very likely making things more complicated for the OS--making it harder for it to determine that you're really just streaming data in and out, and making it more complicated for it to do read-ahead.  It may still figure it out (operating systems are very good at this), but you're probably not helping.

The only benefit in principle is avoiding the cost of a memory copy, but it doesn't sound like that's your goal here (and unless profiling clearly says otherwise, I'd strongly doubt that would help performance).

Comment: mylibrary.read() interfaces with a connected 1394 device, at which point the systems I/O bus is completely idle. Before asking I hacked the same loop in raw C and benchmarked mmap against read()/write(). mmap was ~50% faster.